# Shell hacking: launch bash from csh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, csh

I am trying to set bash as my default shell in my university account.

However, the traditional `chsh` approach does not work here because the university techs have disabled that as a startup shell. But, I can invoke bash by just calling `bash` from my terminal. So, I've developed a small hack that enables my current shell `csh` to start bash automatically by modifying my `~/.cshrc` file so that it calls bash from it. The thing is, I wish to set it up in such way that when I exit my bash session, I want it to close it's parent csh session as well. How can I do that?

**== EDIT ==**

Word of caution: as ajk warned about scripts running with csh, I found out the hard way that the login sequence is done precisely on that shell. I can no longer login into my machine now. I will have to contact my university techs about the removal of the rc file. Which I doubt will make them happy. :\

**So, take heed.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start `bash` like this in your `.cshrc` file:

```
exec bash
```

Preferably, replace `bash` with the full path to `bash`.

Also, be careful if you have to run any script written in `csh`—if it doesn't use `-f`, it will execute your `.cshrc` file before running.  Since you exec `bash` in your `.cshrc`, the script probably won't run as intended.  Writing scripts in `csh` is inadvisable, but I've been in at least one university course that required it.

Comment: Short, sweet, and genius. I completely forgot about `exec`, and it's ability to replace things. Will mark as correct in 3 minutes, when the time limit expires.